# How to run the methods in order for each input given by pytest parametrize

Tags: python, pytest

I have two methods `edit_config` and `get_config`, I'm passing parameters through pytest parametrize. The problem is first edit config will execute for all the inputs and then get_config. But i want to run first edit_config and then get_config for each input like a cycle. How can I do that with along with pytest parametrize?

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("interval, lacp_mode", [("fast", "active"), ("fast", "passive"), ("slow", "active"),
                                                 ("slow", "passive")])
class Example:
    def test_edit_config(self, interval, mode):
        pass
    def test_get_config(self, interval, mode):
        pass
```

actual - runs edit-config first for all parametrize inputs and then get-config

expected - should run edit-config and then get-config like a cycle for each input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pytest create the tests and run them by alphabetical order (default behavior), so the four `test_edit_config` tests will run before `test_get_config` tests.

You can create one test that call the functions of the other tests

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("interval, lacp_mode", [("fast", "active"), ("fast", "passive"), ("slow", "active"), ("slow", "passive")])
class TestExample:

    def test_config(self, interval, lacp_mode):
        self.__edit_config(interval, lacp_mode)
        self.__get_config(interval, lacp_mode)

    def __edit_config(self, interval, lacp_mode):
        pass

    def __get_config(self, interval, lacp_mode):
        pass
```

Another option is to use the [pytest-ordering](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-ordering/) plugin and add the order dynamically

```
def data_provider():
    i = 0
    for data in [("fast", "active"), ("fast", "passive"), ("slow", "active"), ("slow", "passive")]:
        i += 1
        yield pytest.param(data[0], data[1], marks=pytest.mark.run(order=i))


class TestExample:

    @pytest.mark.parametrize('interval, lacp_mode', data_provider())
    def test_edit_config(self, interval, lacp_mode):
        pass

    @pytest.mark.parametrize('interval, lacp_mode', data_provider())
    def test_get_config(self, interval, lacp_mode):
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Tests run independently of each other.

If you want certain actions/tests to be run together, they should be part of one test (if you need setup and tear down actions, the answer is different)

You can organize this in subfunctions which are then called by your test (as I see Guy suggested while I was still working on the second part of my answer):

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("interval, lacp_mode", [("fast", "active"), ("fast", "passive"), ("slow", "active"),
                                                 ("slow", "passive")])
class Example:
    def test_config(self, interval, mode):
        self.do_get_config_test(interval, mode)
        self.do_edit_config_test(interval, mode)

    def do_get_config_test(self, interval, mode):
        pass
    def do_edit_config_test(self, interval, mode):
        pass
```

But I would ask first, why are you doing it this way?  It would make more sense that they would be separate tests.  Perhaps what you really want is separate tests, but with code run *before* the 'edit' tests to set up what is needed (what would be set up by the get_config test).  I find the best way to do this is to use fixtures.

You could have something like:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(params=['fast', 'slow'])
def interval(request):
    return request.param

@pytest.fixture(params=['active', 'passive'])
def mode(request):
    return request.param

@pytest.fixture
def config(interval, mode):
    # set up and return the config for the edit test
    pass

def test_edit_config(config):
    pass
def test_get_config(interval, mode):
    pass
```

Then the 'config' fixture could do whatever setup is necessary for the edit config test, keeping it independent of the get config test.  Then the order would not matter.